# How do you create a design matrix in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to create a design matrix using NumPy for a linear regression function. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np

def linReg(n, parameter):
  X = np.arange(0, n, 1)*2/n
  Y = (X * parameter) + np.random.randn(1)

  return X, Y
```

I am not entirely sure if my X design matrix variable is correct. How would I add a column of 1s to it? Should I use np.append?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding columns to matrix in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827269/adding-columns-to-matrix-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an array of [ones](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html#numpy.ones) by `numpy.ones()` of a shape similar to `a`
then stack them [vertically](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html?highlight=vstack#numpy.vstack) using `vstack()`

```
import numpy as np

def linReg(n, parameter):
  a = np.arange(0, n, 1)*2/n
  i = np.ones(a.shape)
  X = np.vstack((i, a))
  Y = (X * parameter) + np.random.randn(1)
  return X, Y
```

X will look like this

```
array([[1. , 1. , 1. , 1. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 1. , 1.5]])
```

and Y

```
array([[ 2.19576216,  2.19576216,  2.19576216,  2.19576216],
       [-0.80423784,  0.69576216,  2.19576216,  3.69576216]])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a vector with the right dimensions using `numpy.ones`
Let's say your matrix is called mat:

```
n,m = mat.shape # gives you the dimensions of your matrix
ones_vector = np.ones((n,1)) #create a vector of ones same y dimension as your matrix
```

Now you can append the vector to the matrix using `numpy.hstack` ([Doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html))

```
res_front = np.hstack((ones_vector,mat)) # add it to the front
res_back = np.hstack((mat,ones_vector)) # add it to the back
```

Edit: 
So your result would look like this (simplified):

```
print(mat)
[[ 0.2  0.3]
 [ 0.1  0.2]]

print(ones_vector)
[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]]

print(res_back)
[[ 0.2  0.3  1. ]
 [ 0.1  0.2  1. ]]
```